Flutter Gradle plugin migration: Build fails after updating settings.gradle and build.gradle
I've been working on migrating my Flutter project's Gradle configuration from the deprecated apply method to the new plugin DSL syntax. After following the migration steps provided in the Flutter documentation, my project builds and runs successfully with the old settings. However, when I try to update the settings.gradle and build.gradle files as recommended, the build fails with multiple errors.
Here's my current setup:
#### `pubspec.yaml`:
```yaml
name: progetti
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: ^11.1.0
  connectivity_plus: ^6.0.3
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  firebase_core: ^2.32.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.20.0
  provider: ^6.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.5
  intl: ^0.18.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.6
  http: ^1.1.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.1
  confetti: ^0.7.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/logo.png

  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/ic_launcher.png"


#### `settings.gradle`:
```groovy
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.20" apply false
}

include ":app"

// Including plugins with the correct paths
def plugins = [
    "shared_preferences_android-2.2.3",
    "firebase_core-2.32.0",
    "permission_handler_android-12.0.6",
    "geolocator_android-4.6.0",
    "flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.20",
    "firebase_auth-4.20.0",
    "path_provider_android-2.2.4",
    "image_picker_android-0.8.12+3",
    "google_sign_in_android-6.1.24",
    "cloud_firestore-4.17.5",
    "connectivity_plus-6.0.3"
]

plugins.each { plugin ->
    def pluginName = plugin.split('-')[0]
    def pluginVersion = plugin.split('-')[1]
    include ":$pluginName"
    project(":$pluginName").projectDir = new File(settings.ext.flutterSdkPath, ".pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/$plugin/android")
}

android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.progetti"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.progetti"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

local.properties:
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\<your_username>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\path\\to\\flutter

When I run flutter clean, flutter pub get, and flutter run, I get the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Fabio e Elena\AndroidStudioProjects\aidhometest\android\settings.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Project with path ':shared_preferences_android' could not be found.

It seems like the paths to the plugins might be incorrect or something else is wrong with my configuration. I've double-checked the paths in .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ and they seem correct. Any help on what might be causing this issue or how to correctly migrate to the new plugin DSL would be greatly appreciated!
